# Webhook Response Timing Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, shopify, shopify-api

I developed an app for a client I have. They have a Shopify store, and I set up a pythonanywhere account & several webhooks which ping pythonganywhere when they are fired. I perform some advanced tasks which take a few seconds to compute and return.

Shopify requires that I return code 200 to the webhook within 5 seconds. Failing to do this several times in a row causes my webhook to get deleted. For the past few months, I got around this by running a function every 15 seconds that checks to see if all the webhooks exist, and if they don't, to readd them.

However, as my client's order volume has scaled, sometimes the webhook dissapears and in the short period, an order comes in, and that order information and required functions aren't being executed for that 10 second period. An order or two's information sometimes goes missing as a result.

The function that is called while I process the webhook cannot be sped up. Most of the time, I can return a 200 result within 5 seconds. On some occasions, especially with high volume, it can take 10 - 15 seconds.

I have to find a way to return code 200 to the webhook and then process the information I obtained from it.

Example code is below:

```
def example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        example_function(request.json)
        return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

How do I execute the example_function() function but return example() before it is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Another great place to use the `threading` module.
For something simple like this, you can use

```
from threading import Thread

p = Thread(target=example_function, args=(request.json,))
p.start()
```

Instead of calling the function directly. this will start up a seperate thread just for that function and immediately continue execution.

For more complex task queues you can look at Celery or DjangoApScheduler, albeit they have their own amount of over head.

***EDIT***

```
from multiprocessing import Process

P = Process(target=example_functino, args=(request.json,))
p.start()
```

Works in your intsance.

Comment: Considering I am using pythonanywhere to host this flask app, and they do not support threading, is there any other way around it?

Comment: You can try ```from multiprocessing import Process``` but you may run into the same problem. Outside of using another host, (AWS has a $3.5 plan) im not sure. @user2097371